# An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document in weblogic server

Tags: weblogic12c

I am getting the below error in logs when I start weblogic server on my centos machine

> An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

When I enter my username and password below page shows up
[Weblogic error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TGkJ.jpg)

OS version : Centos 7
Weblogic version : 12C

What is the error and how do I solve it?

Comment: Does it say which document.

Comment: @MrLister No it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lot of searching I found the answer.
There was some error in my config.xml file.
So i replaced it with the backup file and the error was solved.